java GUI opens multiple
(I solved the problem, I commented out the whole client class and made the INFO GUI act like the client. no more multiples!)
I have a GUI class where a user enters their username then connects to a server to send the username and get saved in an array, but when i press "connect" to connect with the server and send the username a new GUI opens from the start, I guess a new client is being connected whenever I press connect? I'm not really sure of what's happening
(there is a GUI called menu that opens once a client is connected, from menu u get to the INFO GUI where the problem happens)
I tried to make the code of sending the username to the server in the client class, and made the GUI only send the username to the client but according to the output the username was not getting sent so I changed that
this is a project of my network course so i think the solution of this would be simple since we're still not into complicated stuff . .
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
  
// Server class 
class Server { 
    
    private static ArrayList<String> playersList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void AddPlayer(String name) {
        playersList.add(name) ;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        
        startServer() ;
    } 
  
    // ClientHandler class that will handle multiple clients
    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable { 
        private final Socket clientSocket; 
  
        // Constructor 
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket) 
        { 
            this.clientSocket = socket; 
        } 
  
        @Override
        public void run() 
        { 
            PrintWriter out = null; 
            BufferedReader in = null; 
            try {
                    
                  // get the outputstream of client 
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 
  
                  // get the inputstream of client 
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
  
                String username;
                username = in.readLine() ;
                
                System.out.println("Received username from client: " + username) ;
                
                playersList.add(username) ;
                System.out.println("Updated players list: " + playersList);
                
                WaitingRoom waiting = new WaitingRoom();
                waiting.updatePlayersList(playersList); 
                 
                out.println("Hello, " + username + "! Welcome to the server.");
            }
            catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
            finally { 
                try { 
                    if (out != null) { 
                        out.close(); 
                    } 
                    if (in != null) { 
                        in.close(); 
                        clientSocket.close(); 
                    } 
                } 
                catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
    public static void startServer() {
    ServerSocket server = null;

    try {
        // Server is listening on port 1234
        server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        server.setReuseAddress(true);

        // Running infinite loop for getting client request
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("SERVER STARTED");
            // Socket object to receive incoming client requests
            Socket client = server.accept();

            Menu menu = new Menu() ;
            menu.setVisible(true) ;
                
            // Displaying that new client is connected to server
            System.out.println("New client connected " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

            // create a new thread object
            ClientHandler clientSock = new ClientHandler(client);

            // This thread will handle the client separately
            new Thread(clientSock).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (server != null) {
            try {
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}


Client
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package com.mycompany.wordsgame;


import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*; 
  
// Client class 
class Client { 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            
        // establish a connection by providing host and port number 
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234)) { 
            
            // writing to server 
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); 

            
            // reading from server 
            BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
  
            // object of scanner class 
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
            String line = null; 
            
            // closing the scanner object 
            sc.close(); 
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}

GUI
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package com.mycompany.wordsgame;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.net.*;

public class Info extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    String username ;

    /**
     * Creates new form Info
     */
    public Info() {
        initComponents();
        this.username = jTextField1.getText();
    }
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    public void openGUI() {
    WaitingRoom waitingroom = new WaitingRoom() ;
        waitingroom.setVisible(true) ;
        dispose() ;
}
    
    private void connectToServer(String username) {
        try {
            // Establish connection by providing host and port number
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("Username obtained from GUI: " + username);
            Player player = new Player(username);

            out.println(username);
            out.flush();

            // Open the WaitingRoom GUI after successful connection
            WaitingRoom waitingroom = new WaitingRoom();
            waitingroom.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Username:");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("CONNECT");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 356, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(182, 182, 182)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(140, 140, 140)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(98, 98, 98)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String username = jTextField1.getText();
        
        connectToServer(username);
        
        /*WaitingRoom waitingroom = new WaitingRoom() ;
        waitingroom.setVisible(true) ;
        dispose() ;*/
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    // A Java program for a Client

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Info.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Info().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}


how many main methods do you need? have you checked this? WaitingRoom waitingroom = new WaitingRoom();
waitingroom.setVisible(true);

Why does the server create a new Menu GUI for every client that connects? Why does the server and the client create new WaitingRoom GUIs every time a client connects?

i dont know how to reply here, but the server creates a new menu for each client because each client will have their own interface to enter their information in it

@user23702253 if you don't know what your code does, then it should be expected it can do things you don't expect.
